# Flutter change background every dynamic second

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, mobile

I have a application. Its simply changing background every 1.5 second(default). But I want to control it with a Slider. I changing my state but my timer is inside of initstate. So Its not effecting it. How can i make it ? My Code:

```
Slider(
                              value: features.loopTime,
                              max: 15,
                              min: 0,
                              onChanged: (value) {
                                print(value.toInt());
                                setState(() {
                                  features.loopTime = value;
                                });
                              },
                            ),
```

InitState:

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    var loopTime = features.loopTime * 1000;
    timer = new Timer.periodic(new Duration(milliseconds: loopTime.toInt()), (Timer timer) {
      inspect(loopTime.toInt());
      if (!features.isManual) {
        setState(() {
          features.isBlue = !features.isBlue;
        });
      }
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to cancel timer and reassign. I created function named with _changeTimer() when you slide the slider It will be reassign with new value.

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:developer';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  double _loopTime = 1;
  bool isBlue = false;

  Timer? timer;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    timer = Timer.periodic(Duration(milliseconds: (1000 * _loopTime).toInt()),
        (Timer timer) {
      setState(() {
        isBlue = !isBlue;
      });
    });
  }
  //there 
  _changeTimer() {
    timer!.cancel();
    timer = Timer.periodic(Duration(milliseconds: (1000 * _loopTime).toInt()),
        (Timer timer) {
      setState(() {
        isBlue = !isBlue;
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Material App',
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: isBlue ? Colors.blue : Colors.yellow,
        body: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Slider(
                activeColor: Colors.black,
                value: _loopTime,
                max: 15,
                min: 0,
                onChanged: (value) {
                  setState(() {
                    _loopTime = value;
                    _changeTimer();
                  });
                },
              ),
               Text(_loopTime.toString())
            ],
          ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

https://im3.ezgif.com/tmp/ezgif-3-4b79f96d7e.gif
for demo